# Problem with latex labels using btex and etex in METAPOST

Tags: labels, metapost

The following simple METAPOST code does not compile without error:

```
verbatimtex
%&latex
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
etex
beginfig(1);
z0 = (0,0); z1 = (sqrt(3)*cm,0);
z2 = (sqrt(3)*cm,1cm);
draw z0--z1--z2--cycle;
label.bot(btex $w$ etex, 1/2[z0,z1]);
endfig;
end;
```

The log file states:

```
This is MetaPost, version 2.01 (MiKTeX 22.3)  14 APR 2022 17:40
Sample.mp Preloading the plain mem file, version 1.005) (./Sample.mp
>> Sample.mp
>> Sample.mpx
! ! Unable to read mpx file.
l.10 label.bot(btex
                $w$ etex, 1/2[z0,z1]);
The two files given above are one of your source files
and an auxiliary file I need to read to find out what your
btex..etex blocks mean. If you don't know why I had trouble,
try running it manually through MPtoTeX, TeX, and DVItoMP
```

The mpxerr file states:

```
This is mikTeX, Version 3.141592653 (MiKTeX 22.3) (preloaded format=tex 2022.4.14)  14 APR 
2022 
17:38
restricted \write18 enabled.
%&-line parsing enabled.
**./mp8HtMK1.tex
(mp8HtMK1.tex
! Undefined control sequence.
l.2 \documentclass
              {article}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
l.3 \begin
      {document}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

[1] [1] )
Output written on mp8HtMK1.dvi (2 pages, 340 bytes).
```

I am baffled. I have checked and re-checked the code and it seems to be correct. When compiling it is calling the correct executables (i.e. mpost.exe, latex.exe) What is happening?

I have read related questions in this forum and tried to implement the suggested solutions. Nothing works.

Comment: Not that it helps you, but your code works here (TeXLive 2022, linux). (Both running mpost and mptodpf work.)

Comment: The error says that MikTeX is using `preloaded format=tex` -- plain TeX instead of LaTex, which is why you are getting `Undefined control sequence` from the `\begin{document}`

Comment: @Thruston Yes, indeed. That is what is most puzzling. I checked and it clearly should be using latex.exe. It is told to load latex by the editor. I also checked the paths within MikTeX and they all call the correct executable files. I have absolutely no idea why it is using tex.

Comment: @mickep In TeXLive it works like a charm. I assume then the problem is internal of the executable files within MikTeX? Thanks for your tip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this is 2022, there is really no need to use the antique `%&latex` call with Metapost any more.   The old documents and samples really all need to be updated.

You have two options here:

First, if you just want to try out plain `mpost` and you don't really care about integration with any complex LaTeX format, then replace your preamble so that your MP file looks like this:

```
prologues := 3;
outputtemplate := "%j%c.%{outputformat}";
beginfig(1);
z0 = (0,0); z1 = (sqrt(3)*cm,0);
z2 = (sqrt(3)*cm,1cm);
draw z0--z1--z2--cycle;
label.bot(btex $w$ etex, 1/2[z0,z1]);
endfig;
end;
```

if you compile this with `mpost` it will now create output in Encapsulated PostScript format in a file with an `.eps` extension, which you can view with any PostScript viewer or make into a PDF with `epstopdf` or similar tools.

On the other hand, if you would like to use MP in a more modern style, with all the useful LaTeX formatting if you need it, then switch to using `lualatex` and the `luamplib` package.  Like this:

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document}
\begin{mplibcode}
beginfig(1);
z0 = (0,0); z1 = (sqrt(3)*cm,0);
z2 = (sqrt(3)*cm,1cm);
draw z0--z1--z2--cycle;
label.bot(btex $w$ etex, 1/2[z0,z1]);
endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

Compile this with `lualatex` to produce a PDF file directly.

And actually there is a smart option for labels that lets you get rid of the cumbersome `btex ... etex` mechanism completely.  Checkout the mplib textext option...

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document}
\mplibtextextlabel{enable} % <---- extra option
\begin{mplibcode}
beginfig(1);
z0 = (0,0); z1 = (sqrt(3)*cm,0);
z2 = (sqrt(3)*cm,1cm);
draw z0--z1--z2--cycle;
label.bot("$w$", 1/2[z0,z1]);
endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

Compile this with `lualatex` to get a PDF that looks like this:

[image]

You can read the (sparse) documentation on `luamplib` [here](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/luamplib?lang=en).

Comment: Thank you, Thurston. I appreciate the answer. I am aware that is 2022, and yet I have an important reason (important to me anyway) why I must find a way to properly compile files with such old code. The example is in itself irrelevant. I will try TeXLive, as -mickep pointed in the comment above.